# Internet Explorer browser version specific document mode

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I want my application to be opened in

- *document mode IE-8* for an IE-8 version browser and
- *document mode IE-9* for an IE-9 version browser.

Otherwise the application will fail to open some tabs.

The <meta> tag to force the browser to open in a particular document mode is like this

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

If we dont use a <meta> tag, sometimes the browser is opening our application in a different document mode.

I am using html concept.

Please tell me how we can change the document mode properly according to the browser version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try IE=Edge

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: @SudheerKumarS Glad to help, if my answer helped you, please mark it as right.

Comment: Could you please tell me what does the "content="IE=edge"" means exactly.Will it take latest document mode for a brwoser version?

Comment: @SudheerKumarS yes, roughly, with this meta we ask IE use latest possible document mode for rendering

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"> or do whatever you want
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 9]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"> or do whatever you want
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your answer.But I dont know how to write if else conditions in <head> tag of html page.Could you please provide that.

Comment: Should i use '<!--' and '<!' kind of tags ?Actually meta tag will be commented if i place it in the middle if if and endif block.